# Zend Framework DB >> Query with subquery doesn't work

Tags: php, sql, zend-framework, subquery

I would like to execute an SQL query like this:

```
SELECT a.*, (time - (SELECT time FROM activity
WHERE time < a.time ORDER BY time DESC LIMIT 1) ) AS czas
FROM activity a WHERE 1 LIMIT 6000
```

I have prepared the following code ZF:

```
$activity   = new Application_Model_DbTable_Activity();
$subSql = $activity->select()
//->setIntegrityCheck(false)
->from(array('aw' => 'activity'), array('time'))
->where('time < a.time', '')
->order('time DESC')
->limit(1);

// main query
$sql    = $activity->select()
//->setIntegrityCheck(false)
->from(array('a' => 'activity'), array('a.*', 'czas' => new Zend_Db_Expr('(a.time - (' . $subSql . '))')))
->where(1)
->limit(6000);

$this->rows = $bugs->fetchAll($sql);
```

Unfortunately, this solution does not work. What should I improve?

Sorry for my english

Comment: Is there any error messages?

Comment: Fatal:Fatal error: Call to a member function fetchAll() on a non-object in /path/CronController.php on line 38

Comment: OK. Stupid is with me. I did not notice that I refer to the wrong variable (object) >> $bugs-> instead $activity->